# Opennes via Open Neighborhoods

Tags: geometric-topology

Let A be a subset of a Euclidean space. Show that a subset *U* of A is open if for each point *p* in *U*, there exists an open set *V* in A containing *p*.

We have relative open sets. I know from point set topology that these corresponds to neighborhoods of points. If for such *p*'s we intersect *V* with *U* and take their union we get the set *U*, but I dont understand how that makes *U* open in A.

Comment: Since $U\subseteq A$, $V\cap U=V\cap A$ and $V\cap U$ is open in $A$.  Does that resolve your difficulty?

Comment: I think it is because U is open in that union of neighborhoods and the union is also open in our original set A. Hence that makes U open in A.